# Singular homology and induced homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $A$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$, consider $i: A \to X$ the inclusion map and $H_0(i):H_0(A) \to H_0(X)$ the homomorphism induced by the inclusion map $i$ on the $0$-singular homology module.

How to show that the following equivalence is true:

$H_0(i)$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ Each path-component of $X$ contains at most one path-component of $A$.

My textbook left this as an exercise but I can't prove it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$H_0(X)$ is the free abelian group on the path components. If $c$ is a component of $A$ then $i_*c $ is the component of $X$ containing $c$.

Assume that $i_*$ is injective, then if two components $c$ and $d$ of $A$ are in the same $X$ component then $i_*(c-d)=0$, a contradiction.

Now assume that at most one $A$ component is in an $X$ component.
If $i_*(\sum n_ic_i)=0$ then $\sum n_i i_* c_i=0$. Now $i_*c_i\neq i_*c_j$ for $i\neq j$ because of our assumption. Since $H_0(X)$ is free this implies that $n_i=0$ so $i_*$ is injective.